High frequency service call cause the freeze of service client on ros2
The service client sometimes freeze in spin_until_future_complete on high frequency service call.
I run 1 service server and 3 service clients which call service on high frequency.
I tested it on ros:jazzy docker image using attached regeneration codes.
Attached are python codes, but same result on c++ codes.
Is this correct behavior of service call?
Service Server
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from example_interfaces.srv import AddTwoInts

class MinimalService(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_service')
        self.srv = self.create_service(AddTwoInts, 'add_two_ints', self.add_two_ints_callback)

    def add_two_ints_callback(self, request, response):
        response.sum = request.a + request.b
        return response

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    minimal_service = MinimalService()
    rclpy.spin(minimal_service)
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Service Client (run on 3 terminals)
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from example_interfaces.srv import AddTwoInts

class MinimalClientAsync(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_client_async')
        self.cli = self.create_client(AddTwoInts, 'add_two_ints')
        while not self.cli.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
            self.get_logger().info('service not available, waiting again...')

    def send_request(self, a, b):
        self.req = AddTwoInts.Request()
        self.req.a = a
        self.req.b = b
        self.future = self.cli.call_async(self.req)
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, self.future)
        return self.future.result()

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    minimal_client = MinimalClientAsync()
    for i in range(1000000000):
        response = minimal_client.send_request(1, 2)
        if i%10000 == 0:
            minimal_client.get_logger().info(
                'Result of add_two_ints: for %d + %d = %d' %
                (1, 2, response.sum))

    minimal_client.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```


Looks to me like you are running as fast as the CPU let's you run for 1000000000 iterations. You probably simply have 100% CPU. Can we see your htop how to htop?

Thank you for your reply.  Yes, the CPU usage of the service server is about 100% on 1 CPU core, and below 1% for service clients on other cores.
The slow down of computation is OK, but the problem is service client doesn't progress at all when it freeze. Even though 2 of 3 clients are terminated, the freezed client doesn't continue the computation loop.

Could you please motivate the issue? Why is it useful to run that many service-requests as fast as possible? Are you trying to find the ROS-core limitations?

I'm developing a robotic system that uses ros2. I encountered some strange freezes on several oss packages, and I found these freezes are caused by service call. So I created above scripts for the accelerated test. The freeze occurs not only high frequency cases but also low frequency multi client cases. I think ros2 have a bug on service call that affect all packages using service call.

Please see I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?

Has anyone reproduced the freeze?

Created a issue of rcl. https://github.com/ros2/rcl/issues/1163
